# macOS interrupt application launch

Tags: macos, startup, sandbox

Is there any way to interrupt an application-launch and grab all arguments?

---

Background: I want to write a sandboxing-tool to inject user-specified sandbox-profiles automatically before the application starts.
So if the user (or another app) opens e.g. Firefox, my application will grab all arguments, cancel the start and open Firefox (with all arguments) in the sandbox.